# Files accessed by a process, c# , deviare

Tags: c#, process

I need to find out the files accessed by a given (hook) process. what am i suppose to achieve that using c# and deviare?

Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you asking for a list of local files currently opened by a process?

Comment: If you want to hook a process use Deviare, if you want to monitor a process's file access you could use Process Monitor http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: @Daniel, yes. May i know how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Deviare](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/) examples to hook without writing code. There are 2 applications that let you hook any process and watch their API calls in a console. The source code of those applications is available and easy to follow. You have examples in C# and C++.